# AOP throwing Exception

Tags: java, maven, aspectj, aop

I am writting my first AOP code. i have added the code and related depencies using **maven 3.3** however I am getting the below exception when i try to run my code although it compiles fine.

I suspect this is related to the versioning/compatibility of the dependencies i have added in the pom with **java 7.**

**Exception:**

```
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryInterfaceAwareBeanPostProcessor#0': BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.config.internalEhCacheCachingAdvisor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.impl.CacheStaticMethodMatcherPointcut#0' while setting bean property 'pointcut'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.impl.CacheStaticMethodMatcherPointcut#0': BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0' while setting bean property 'transactionAttributeSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0': BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/weaver/BCException
```

**POM.XML:**

```
<dependency>
                    <groupId>asm</groupId>
                    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                </dependency>
                 <dependency>
                    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                      <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                      <version>1.7.0</version>
                </dependency>
```

**App-Context xml:**

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy></aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
      <bean id="models" class="com.myproject.models.Users"><property name="name" value="Dummy Name"></property></bean>
      <bean id="userservice" class="com.myproject.userService"><property name="users" ref="models"></property></bean>
      <bean name="userAroundadvice" class="com.myproject.models.Aopclass" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Per root cause `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/weaver/BCException`,
`aspectjweaver.jar` is not in your classpath, add following dependency in your `pom`:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hi Harsh, Thanks for responding.. i tried adding aspectjweaver  dependency too  I still get the same issue. :(